# cannot run node after migrating macs from an intel chip with monterey 12.6 to M1 chip sonoma 14.0

Tags: zsh, apple-m1

I'm having trouble after migration computers from a mac with intel chip running monterey 12.6 to an M1 running sonoma 14.0

when I open projects in vs code some commands work but most don't. npm installing worked in one repo but took 10 minutes and is not working in others. I'm also using zsh. I believe this may be inherited from my last computer which had path issue with node and zsh.

for example I'm not able to run jest tests or spin up dev servers with webpack.  earlier when I ran brew upgrade node it said xcrun error, so I installed command line tools. then it said node not found to I reinstalled node with brew.

I've tried reinstalling node in homebrew and upgrading

brew doctor, s

also tried unlinking and relinking node

brew unlink node
brew link node